# Причастия переходят в прилагательные или наоборот (крашеный, мороженый и др.)?

Tags: грамматика, словообразование, прилагательные, причастия

1. **[Статья](https://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/morfologia/prichastie/perehod-prichastiy-v-imena-prilagatelnie-v-russkom-yazike/521/?q=463&n=521): Пepexoд пpичacтий в имeнa пpилaгaтeльныe в pyccкoм языкe**

Haличиe y пpичacтий пpизнaкoв, oбщиx c имeнaми пpилaгaтeльными, cпocoбcтвyeт **пepexoдy пpичacтий в имeнa пpилaгaтeльныe.** Этoт пepexoд, нaблюдaвшийcя в пpeдшecтвyющиe пepиoды иcтopии pyccкoгo языкa, интeнcивнo ocyщecтвляeтcя в нaшe вpeмя. B coвpeмeннoм языкe ecть cлoвa, coвepшeннo yтpaтившиe пpиcyщyю им нeкoгдa глaгoльнocть и **пpeвpaтившиecя в oбычныe пpилaгaтeльныe** (oткpoвeнный oт oтъкpыти, oбыкнoвeнный oт oбыкнyти и пoдoбныe: cвящeнный, блaжeнный...

Гpyппy пpичacтныx oбpaзoвaний пo пpoиcxoждeнию cocтaвляют пpилaгaтeльныe типa ***cyшeный, мoчeный,*** cвязь кoтopыx c пpoизвoдящими глaгoлaми eщe oтчeтливa и в coвpeмeннoм языкe.

Baлгинa H.C., Poзeнтaль Д.Э., Фoминa M.И. Coвpeмeнный pyccкий язык — M., 2002г.

2. Но это **историческая грамматика**.  Но  в Грамматике под ред. Шведовой (1 том) эти прилагательные **образуются от глаголов**  с помощью суффиксов ***ЕН, Н.*** При наличии **зависимых слов** эти глагольные формы считаются **причастиями.**

**Вопрос:**

**Какое суждение** верно в современном языке для этой группы слов? Эти прилагательные образуются от глаголов или это  причастия перешли в прилагательные?

***Крашеный*** — при морфемном разборе выделяют суффикс **ЕН**. А при словообразовательном разборе как? Это **непроизводное** слово?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А можно я тупо скопипащу?

[Как происходит переход причастия в прилагательное](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/glagol/prichastie/perehod-prichastiya-v-prilagatelnoe.html#i-1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [Проанализируем](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/glagol/prichastie/perehod-prichastiya-v-prilagatelnoe.html#i-1) словосочетания «шагающий экскаватор» и «удивленный
> вид», пытаясь заменить их на однокоренной глагол.
>
> Шагающий экскаватор — это отнюдь не тот, кто идет пешком; удивленный
> вид — это вовсе не вид, который удивили.
>
> Значит, эти слова потеряли признак по действию, что кардинально
> отличает причастие, а стали обозначать чистый признак предмета. В
> данном случае произошёл переход причастия в прилагательное, которое
> входит в состав технического термина (шагающий экскаватор) и
> приобретает переносное лексическое значение.
>
> Аналогичным способом образовано множество прилагательных. Отметим
> переход причастий в прилагательные в сочетаниях:
>
> ведущий корову на луг — ведущий специалист (главный, компетентный);
> сдержанная всадником лошадь — сдержанный ответ (скупой, сухой,
> немногословный);  упавший тополь во время бури — упавший голос (тихий,
> слабый); избитый волк — избитая истина (банальная, очевидная).
>
> **Вывод**
>
> В тех сочетаниях, где используется прилагательное, оно имеет
> переносное лексическое значение и к нему можно привести синонимичное
> качественное прилагательное, что еще раз подтверждает потерю словом
> признака по действию и принадлежность его к другой части речи —
> прилагательному.

---

[Словообразовательный разбор отличается от морфемного тем, что при словообразовательном разборе нужно найти слово, от которого оно образовано, например: слово слушатель образовано от слова слушать,
а при морфемном разборе нужно найти морфемы, из которых состоит слово, например: слово слушатель состоит из корня -слуш-, суффиксов -а- и -тель и нулевого окончания.](https://resh.edu.ru/subject/lesson/6963/conspect/260136/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня! Вам все можно!  Вспомнила смешной эпизод из книги…Вам для хорошего  настроения, отличная книга
 https://www.rulit.me/books/zavidnoe-chuvstvo-very-steninoj-read-397644-1.html

Comment: Хотя ответ не разбирает строго назначенного слова ***крашеный***, в нём есть всё на все случаи... Приди меня лайкнуть на БВ: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4291839-kuda-delis-dvorovye-pesni.html#answer12197226 и http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4244759-na-vash-vybor-instituta-vlijali-roditeli-pochemu.html#answer12080628 - плииз!

Comment: Круто! Картинки, песенки – все буду слушать. И ваша история интересная!

Comment: Шаронушка, у меня есть прекрасные ответы, это уже писательский уровень, "стиль"; после смерти Мани некому стало мной восторгаться; приходи на БВ - я тебя там сориентирую, покажу, кого стоит читать, там и энциклопедистка моя любимая - Удивительная Рядом http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/profile17401/

Comment: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4244759-na-vash-vybor-instituta-vlijali-roditeli-pochemu.html#answer12080628

Answer (score 1):

```
 – Я с трудом понимаю, зачем сегодня нужны журналисты, – 
 сообщил Супермен коллективу. – Вся информация есть в 
 Интернете, бери да читай.

 – А там она, по-вашему, откуда берётся? – возмутился 
 корреспондент отдела культуры. – Журналисты и пишут.

 – Я думаю, – сказал Супермен, не переставая улыбаться, – 
 что мы будем брать материалы в Интернете. И нам не 
 требуется такой большой коллектив.

 Вот тогда-то вперёд шагнула Юля Калинина – ей не хватало 
 только знамени в руках! Вместо знамени Юлька держала в 
 руках свежую газетную полосу.

 – То есть будем копипастить?

 – Чего? – испугался Супермен...
```

**Исповедь  прилагательного «крашеный»**

*Все мы когда-то были причастиями, а теперь **разбрелись кто куда.** Кто-то перешел в прилагательные и родства не помнит, кто-то остался верен глаголу, а кто и на пары разбился: причастие — прилагательное.*

*И только я со товарищи **ходим туда-сюда**: то причастие, а то прилагательное.  **Перекрашиваемся!** Уже и не знаем, кто мы.
Так бы и ничего, но вот **словообразовательный разбор!** С нас же спрашивают!*

*И вот что я,  **непроизводное** прилагательное?  А **суффикс** откуда взял?*